# How to calculate Big Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Please can someone tell me how `2n = O(3n)` is calculated?

Here's some other examples:

`2^4 = O(1)`
`10n = O(n)`
 `n log2(n) = O(n log n)`

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Please could you elaborate.

Comment: n log^2(n) = O(n log n) is wrong. Do you mean n log_2(n)?

Comment: Are you sure that `n log^2(n) = O(n log n)` is really truth? I think it is not.

Comment: @Gaim: You inserted a `^` where there was not one. That notation means base-2 `log`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a rigorous mathematical definition of big-O:

f(*x*) is O(g(*x*)) if there exist values *x0* >= 0 and *k* > 0 such that for all *x* > *x0*, f(*x*) <= k*g(*x*).

To prove statements about the big-O classification of functions, you must show how to find the *x0* and *k* values.

Comment: +1 for giving a correct answer. Knowing the definition is the first step to answering a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
2^4 = 2^4 * 1 <= 2^4 * 1
```

so `2^4` is `O(1)` with constant `2^4`.

```
10 * n = 10 * n <= 10 * n
```

so `10 * n` is `O(n)` with constant `10`.

```
n log2 n = n log n / log 2 <= (1 / log 2) * n log n
```

so `n log2 n` is `O(n log n)` with constant `1 / log 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, use the definition of the asymptotic notation, then produce a proof that f(n) = O(g(n)), where f(n) is your function and g(n) is the bound you are trying to prove.

For your first example:

```
2n =? O(3n)
f(n) = 2n, g(n) = 3n
need c such that for n > n0, f(n) <= c*g(n); guess c = 1
We have f(n) = 2n <= 3n = c*g(n) for n >= 0, so
2n = f(n) = O(g(n)) = O(3n)
```

For your second example:

```
2^4 =? O(1)?
f(n) = 2^4, g(n) = 1
need c such that for n > n0, f(n) <= c*g(n); guess c = 2^4 + 1
We have f(n) = 2^4 <= 2^4 + 1 = c*g(n), so
2^4 = f(n) = O(g(n)) = O(1)
```

Your third example is practically equivalent to the first.

Your fourth example is wrong; it is false that

```
n log^2(n) = O(n log n)
```

It is true that

```
n log(n^2) = O(n log n)
```

But that's a different expression. To see that n log^2(n) is not O(n log n), we can argue thusly: let c be an arbitary fixed constant. We can find an n such that c*n*log(n) < n*log^2(n). We get

```
c*n*log(n) < n*log^2(n)
c < log(n)
```

So choose n = 2^(c+1). Therefore, there is no n0 such that, for n > n0, f(n) <= c*g(n).

EDIT: In the fourth example, if you mean by "log2(n)" the log-base-two of n, then yes, nlog2(n) = O(nlogn). Typically, in doing algorithmic complexities, the logarithm is understood to be to base two, unless otherwise specified. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of proving this:

One could be the use of the limit:

f(n) = O(g(n)) iff the following holds:

```
                f(n)
   limsup    ----------  < infinity
x->infinity     g(n)
```

So, if you take `2n/(3n)` in the limit, this is `1.5`.

Comment: Cool ascii art which remembers me that tomorrow I've got a test about it, -1 (just kidding ;) )

Comment: -1. Not a bad answer, but I will point out that this is less complete than the other up-voted answers. For instance, this technique cannot classify f(n) = n*cos(n) as O(n), nor can it classify f(n) for which no known closed-form expression exists. Acknowledge the limitations and I'll be happy to delete the comment and remove the downvote.

Comment: @Patrick87 I think it can classify f(n)=n*cos(n) in O(n), because `n*cos(n)/n=cos(n)<=1`, thus in `O(n)`. Moreover, things like these are rarely useful in the context of runtime analysis which is what I supposed the OP wants the O-notation use for.

Comment: @phimuemue Well, at best, you would have to be giving a fairly non-intuitive interpretation to your method to argue that it says unambiguously that f(n) = n*cos(n) is O(n)... the limit isn't defined, at least not in the usual elementary sense. To make your post more palatable would basically be saying that f(n)/g(n) is bounded by a constant as n approaches infinity, which is equivalent to the definition of the big-Oh notation used in the other answers. Also, what about the point about closed-form expressions for f(n) and g(n)?